# Difference between r2_score and score() in linear regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I found the results of score() in LinearRegression is different from r2_score(). I expected them to return the same results.The codes are as below:

```
r2_train = np.empty(shape=[10, 0])
r2_train_n = np.empty(shape=[10, 0])

for set_degree in range (0,10):
    pf = PolynomialFeatures(degree= set_degree)
    X_train_tf = pf.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(11,1))
    X_test_tf = pf.transform(X_test.reshape(4,1))
    lr = LinearRegression().fit(X_train_tf, y_train)

    r2_train = np.append(r2_train, r2_score(lr.predict(X_train_tf), y_train))
    r2_train_n = np.append(r2_train_n, lr.score(X_train_tf, y_train))
```

Comment: You've mixed up the inputs to `r2_score`. Check the documentation for which positional argument should be the true values and which should be the predictions.

Comment: My mistake. Thank you so much. I got a better understanding of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*score()* :- It is just comparing the error/residual in between the actual values and the  predicted values.

*r2_score()* :-  it is the value which specifies the amount of the residual across the whole dataset.

The r2 score is more robust and quite often used accuracy matrix.

It is calculated as

****(r2_score = 1 - (RSS / TSS))****

Where(RSS = Residual Sum of Sqaure & TSS = Total Sum of sqaure). While performing the regression by using the OLS method you should also consider the value of *adjustedR2*

Comment: Thank you so much. It really helps.

Answer (score 2):

In using r2_score, you made it:

```
r2_score(lr.predict(X_train_tf), y_train)
```

According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html), the first argument should be the true values, i.e. it should be:

```
r2_score(y_train, lr.predict(X_train_tf))
```

This will give similar result with the score method in LinearRegression()

Same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45529907/difference-between-model-score-vs-r2-score)